# undefined method error ^ in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying out rails for the first time and I keep getting this undefined method error. All I did so far was just use rails to create a new project and the scaffold to create my database table called test. After applying the rate command everything works but when i run it in a web browser it gives me this error:

```
ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method `^' for "7":String) on line #3 of app/views/tests/new.html.erb:
1: <h1>New test</h1>
2: 
3: <% form_for(@test) do |f| %>
4:   <%= f.error_messages %>
5: 
6:   <p>
```

Anyone with any ideas on how I can deal with this error?

**EDIT:-**

"new" action in controller:-

```
def new
  @test = Test.new 
  respond_to do |format| 
     format.html # new.html.erb 
     format.xml { render :xml => @test } 
  end
end
```

Comment: instead of posting code in the comment, edit the question and post it there.

Answer (score 2):

The error message complains because Rails tried to use the `^` operator on the string "7", which doesn't support that operation (the number 7 would support that operation). The line indicated in the backtrace is `form_for(@test)`, so `form_for` does something to `@test` which causes `^` to be called on `7`. The most likely reason for that is that Rails tries to xor `@test`'s id somewhere and unexpectedly `@test.id` returns the string `"7"` instead of the number `7`.

In other words you probably set up the `tests` table to have an id column with a string type instead of integer, which Rails does not like.

Comment: I still get a similar error when i define by fields as different types. Is it a problem with my gems or something caused i reinstalled my gems and i'm still having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have assigned something to `@test` that isn't a model object. Please post the code for the `new` method from your controller so we can dig into this further.

Comment: def new
    @test = Test.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @test }
    end
  end

Comment: thats the new method from my controller

Comment: I don't see why that would possibly cause such an error. Using ruby 1.9 passing in a non-AR object into `form_for` will cause an error about the `id` method not existing, not about `^`. Using ruby `1.8` you'd get a warning about `Object#id` being deprecated and then it'd return an object id, not a string like `"7"`. Either way you wouldn't get the described error message.